# How to generate shadow under words on an image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

```
public static System.Drawing.Image GenerateGiftCard(String text, Font font, Color textColor)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = Bitmap.FromFile(@"G:\xxx\images\gift-card.jpg");
    Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
    SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);

    //create a brush for the text
    Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

    float x, y;

    x = img.Width / 2 - textSize.Width / 2;
    y = img.Height / 2 - textSize.Height / 2;

    drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, x, y);

    drawing.Save();

    textBrush.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    return img;
}
```

But the text generated by this code is "plain" not dimensional and no shadow beneath it.

This is the font **style** I want:

[image: Beautiful characters]

**Is there anything I can do to generate the same style via my code?**

**Does anyone know how to use SiteMapPath or ResolveURL objects to transfer a relative path to a physical one? cheers,**

Comment: [Shadow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xeawz664(v=vs.80).aspx) - To create the shadow, the text is drawn twice. The first time it is in gray and offset. The second time is in black.

Comment: @AVD good idea, I'll try it now and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @AVD but how to do the font style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First render the shadow by drawing the text with a darker, optionally translucent brush at an offset.  After the shadow is rendered, overlay the regular text.

**Example**:

```
public static System.Drawing.Image GenerateGiftCard(String text, Font font, Color    textColor, Color shadowColor, SizeF shadowOffset)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = Bitmap.FromFile(@"G:\xxxx\images\gift-card.jpg");
    Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
    SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);

    //create a brush for the text
    Brush shadowBrush = new SolidBrush(shadowColor); // <-- Here
    Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

    float x, y;

    x = img.Width / 2 - textSize.Width / 2;
    y = img.Height / 2 - textSize.Height / 2;

    drawing.DrawString(text, font, shadowBrush, x + shadowOffset.Width, y + shadowOffset.Height); // <-- Here
    drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, x, y);

    drawing.Save();

    textBrush.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: thx for your reply. do you have any idea about the font style? Plus, do you know how to use SiteMapPath or ResolveURL objects to transfer a relative path to a physical one? cheers,

Comment: I don't know about the font style.  I don't recognize it.  If you want to resolve a URL, I'm sure there is a Stack Overflow question just for that, but if you don't want to look it up, try `Server.MapPath("~/path/file.ext")`.

Comment: finally, the Server.MapPath() is what I was looking for and it works. A big Thank you :)